# Docker push failed due to "access denied... private image"

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I am part of an organization on Docker Hub and am trying to push a new image to the repository. Here is the commands I am running:

```
$ docker login
Username (<username>): <username>
Login Succeeded
$ docker push <org-name>/<repo-name>:<tag-name>
The push refers to a repository [<group name>/<image name>] (len: 1)
Sending image list
FATA[0003] Error: Status 400 trying to push repository <group name>/<image name>: "Access denied: <hash> is a private image"
```

I've searched for this error message and not found anything. What does the error mean? I've also searched for "private image" and not found any official documentation on them.

Comment: I had something similar with a docker 1.4 rc or such, so what gives `docker info`and `docker version`

Comment: Yeah, I was using 1.5. Upgrading the version fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best answer, but I upgraded to Docker 1.6 and this fixed the issue.